# Append contents of previous row to the next one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recursion

A bit stuck here. Seems easy but for some reason can't seem to get it to work.

I have a csv file that I need to read from and then add contents of the previous row to the next one. So for example if original data looks like this:

```
   0
0  a
1  b
2  c
3  d
```

Then I need to get it to be like this:

```
   a  b  c
0  a  0  0
1  b  a  0
2  c  b  a
3  d  c  b
```

I tried with Pandas first, but then quickly got lost in trying to find a simple and quick way of iterating over rows/columns.

After all this didn't quite work I decided to simply read the csv line-by-line and then recursively add data to the previous row's contents, but been unsuccessful so far in it constantly running into recursion limit issues and such.

What would be the best way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC we can do the `cumsum` then do the `split` and  `sorted`

```
s=df.iloc[:,0].add(',').cumsum().str[:-1].str.split(',',expand=True).T.apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.notnull))
      0     1     2  3
0  None  None  None  a
1  None  None     a  b
2  None     a     b  c
3     a     b     c  d

#s=s.iloc[:,::-1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The only issue I have is that the order is reversed in the code you provided. I need the original data (a,b,c,d) to be in the first column and so on. What do I change to get it reversed the other way around?

Comment: @pavel s=s.iloc[:,::-1] :-)

Comment: Thanks! And what if I needed to do the same but with two columns simultaneously?

Comment: @pavel do both of them by two line, then join them together

Answer (score 2):

Just a for loop would do:

```
for i in range(1,3):
    # may need to replace '0' with 0 or the actual column name
    # also i with f'{i}' if you want column name as string
    df[i] = df['0'].shift(i, fill_value=0)

    # another column to shift:
    df[f'other_col_{i}'] = df['other_col'].shift(i, fill_value=0)
```

If you have even more than two columns, maybe something similar to ALollz's excellent deleted answer:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
new_df = pd.concat([df[cols].shift(i, fill_value=0).add_suffix(f'_{i}')
                      for i in range(3)
                   ])
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2
0  a  0  0
1  b  a  0
2  c  b  a
3  d  c  b
```

Comment: Thanks! This works! But what if I had two columns that I needed to shift simultaneously? How would I go around doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe? I am not sure what the logic is in your example for adding the next row but here is my solution based on some assumptions I made

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("yourcsv.csv")

for item in df['firstcolname']:
   temp_list = [0] * len(df.columns)
   while len(temp_list) != len(df['firstcolname']):
      for element in df['firstcolname']:
         temp_list.append(element)

   df[item] = temp_list
```

Answer (score 1):

I bit changed YOBEN_S Answer for your requirement.

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
s=df.iloc[:,0].add(',').cumsum().str[:-1].str.split(',',expand=True).T.apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.notnull))

s=s.iloc[:,::-1]

new_header = s.iloc[:,0] #grab the first col
s.columns = new_header #set the header row as the df header
s.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)

print(s)
```

Output

```
3  A  B  C  D
0  A  0  0  0
1  B  A  0  0
2  C  B  A  0
3  D  C  B  A
```